# Can't build and install Erlang on pcduino

Tags: build, erlang, arm

I have just got my pcduino. I want to write my programs using Erlang and want to use version R16B (so I can use web sockets). When  I download and builds R16 the pcduino runs out of virtual memory so the make fails. Has anyone succeeded to install R16 or later versions on an Pcduino?

Comment: Let me know how this goes.

Answer (score 0):

Erlang-Solutions has done some work on [embedded Erlang](http://www.erlang-embedded.com/). They don't mention the pcduino as one of the platforms they've successfully run on, but their general advice is to cross-compile, rather than build directly on the target. ([Conquering Embedded Devices
with Erlang](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/sites/default/files/trimedia/EUG-Krakow-embedded.pdf))

Here's an example of cross-compiling Erlang from that paper.

```
$ ./configure -host=arm-linux --with-ssl=/home/development/arm-lib/ --prefix=/opt/erlangR13B04 --without-termcap --disable-hipe --disable-smp-support --disable-megaco-flex-scanner --disable-megaco-reentrant-flex-scanner
make noboot
sudo make install
```

They also suggest removing the `+debug_info` flag from makefiles before building, running `beam_lib:strip_release(code:root_dir()).`, and having the compiler optimize for space (`-Os`) to produce small binaries.